# Query to always show latest values

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table that is:

```
date         name     value

1/1/14        x        1

1/1/14        z        1

2/1/14        x        2

6/1/14        y        3

7/1/14        x        3

10/1/14       y        4
```

I would like to write a query that returns for every date existing in the table a list of all the most recent values for every 'name' if they existed at that date.
I'm not sure if its possible though.

So the query output would look like this

```
date     name    value
1/1/14    x        1
1/1/14    z        1
2/1/14    x        2
2/1/14    z        1
6/1/14    x        2
6/1/14    y        3
6/1/14    z        1
7/1/14    x        3
7/1/14    y        3
7/1/14    z        1
10/1/14    x        3
10/1/14    y        4
10/1/14    z        1
```

Comment: This is (My)SQL, so those are not dates :-(

Comment: point taken on the dates.....but if they were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, although it requires a somewhat complex query.  First you have to generate the list of all the rows, then you need to get the value.  The following query uses a `cross join` for the first part and a correlated subquery for the second:

```
select d.date, n.name,
       (select s.value
        from simple s
        where s.name = n.name and s.date <= d.date
        order by s.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as value
from (select distinct date from simple s) d cross join
     (select distinct name from simple n) n;
```

Comment: OK - actually it does but its very close - and very appreciated.
it returns Nulls for those names not actually in the table by that date. So I could wrap it all in a query with a where not null in it.

Comment: @user1479891  . . . What would you want it to return if there are no matching values?